# Open a Model made in 2.82 in 2.79B

Tags: modeling, texturing

I have been working with blender 2.82 but in my new laptop, blender 2.82 will NOT work.. something is causing an issue..   It was causing Blender and the computer to freeze up..  Microsoft checked the dump file and said I had a problem with the graphics card.. had me roll back the drivers to a previous one.. I did that.. now blender don't freeze anymore, BUT it will NOT stay open.. In 2 minutes after opening Blender, it just closes down...  I did an update on the NVIDIA GeForce MX250 graphics card to the newest one from NVIDIA and now as soon as I open Blender and try to add texture,  it freezes up Blender and the computer where I have to turn off the computer and reboot..
  Unless someone has a solution for me to run Blender 2.82,  I'm stuck only being able to use 2.79B ... it works...  I have a building I was creating in Blender 2.82 but I can't get it textured because of the problem.. I'd like to move it to 2.79B and just work in it 
   Can I do that and how

Comment: You can open 2.8x files in 2.8 only. There are also the version 2.81 and 2.80 to try. If you want to open the file in 2.79, you can (1) try copying and pasting it with the hotkey or (2) exporting it as another format (e.g. obj / fbx).

Comment: I can not believe that there is no way running blender 2.8x on your notebook without any issues. I've got no *real* graphics card (integrated grahics) in my notebook and blender 2.83 is running fine (on arch though). Latest drivers installed?

Comment: My graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce MX250..  with the newest driver..   Blender 2.80, 2.81 and 2.82 freeze up on me or it just shuts down ..  Since I got this new laptop, I have NOT been able to use these three versions.. I've tried all three of them.. NOTHING... I can't figure out why...  My old laptop had no issues running these versions of Blender...  I'm stumped as to what the issue is... nothing else is having issues in the laptop..  I can play videos, work photoshop, play games but Blender freezes up on me and sometimes it just closes down.. if it freezes I have to turn off the computer